# Testing code which uses ScheduledExecutorService (without using Sleep)

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, junit, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a validation object which runs input through a series of checks. If an input fails any of the checks, the validation ends.

Inputs which pass all the checks get grouped based on a sliding time window. This window kicks off when the first piece of input arrives. So this is the flow:

1. First input arrives.
2. Input passes all checks.
3. Since there is no active timer, input is put in a new basket. Timer window begins for N seconds.
4. Any subsequent input passing all checks within this timer window will get grouped into the same basket.
5. Once the timer goes off, the basket is dispatched.
6. Any further valid input will start a new timer, and the process repeats.

At the moment, to make sure valid inputs get grouped together properly, I'm using Thread.sleep in the unit tests (i.e. Once I send a number of inputs, I sleep for a few seconds, then wake up and make sure the basket which got dispatched contains everything expected).

This is starting to become annoying as I have over 700 unit tests and this test collection is the bottleneck each time I run the complete suite.

The time window is simply a ScheduledExecutorService. To be able to test this functionality more quickly, should I create a settable time window object?

Comment: You might consider adding an additional tag or two to your question so it can be targeted to the appropriate audience. Eg. What language are you coding in, what is your unit test framework, etc. Why should we waste time giving you inappropriate answers.

Comment: To further my comment, there is a nice solution for tests involving timers/something that sleeps in AngularJs. But that's obviously not what you're using :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Done.

Answer (score 15):

Your "unit tests" sound a little bit like *integration tests*.  You are not only testing the unit that uses the `ScheduledExecutorService`, but you are also testing the `ScheduledExecutorService` itself.

A better approach would be to *inject* a *mock* `ScheduledExecutorService`.  In other words, you shouldn't need to test that the timed event actually happens four seconds later; you should only need to test that your unit *asked* the scheduler to run it four seconds later.

That's where mocks come in.  You inject the mock scheduler, perform some operation on your unit that should cause it to interact with the scheduler, and then you can interrogate the mock to verify that the interaction actually happened in the expected way.

If you do it right, each test case can complete in milliseconds or maybe microseconds instead of seconds.

Answer (score 4):

I have found, that [DeterministicScheduler](https://github.com/jmock-developers/jmock-library/blob/2.12.0/jmock/src/main/java/org/jmock/lib/concurrent/DeterministicScheduler.java#L28) *(from [jMock](http://jmock.org/threading-scheduler.html) lib)* is the nice way to test code, which uses `ScheduledExecutorService`.

It provides similar functionality like [TestScheduler](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/schedulers/TestScheduler.html) provides for code, which uses RxJava or [DelayController](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-delay-controller/advance-time-by.html) for Kotlin code, which uses coroutine.

In both cases [`tick()`](https://github.com/jmock-developers/jmock-library/blob/2.12.0/jmock/src/test/java/org/jmock/test/unit/lib/concurrent/DeterministicSchedulerTests.java#L288) does exactly the same as `advanceTimeBy()` is doing in earlier mentioning libs:
it moves *virtual time forward* and runs any task, which is expected to be executed within given *time frame*.

You would need to add core jMock lib in order to use it.

E.g. using Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    //Used only as provider of DeterministicScheduler (test implementation of ScheduledExecutorService)
    testImplementation("org.jmock:jmock:2.12.0")
}
```

Off topic: as far as I can see it's general purouse functionality, which is not related to jMock mocking functionality.
Ideally it would be nice to provide it as a separate JAR/maven artifact so that people can easily pull it without adding whole jmock lib.
I have crated [an issue](https://github.com/jmock-developers/jmock-library/issues/196) with this suggestion already.

Answer (score 2):

It's surprisingly tough to make `ScheduleExecutorService` itself testable. Frustratingly its implementation (`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`) does have a `now()` method. In principle you could override this and control the time! The problem is that the method is package-private and final, so it's not available to be overridden.  It might be possible to override this using something like PowerMock.

If you can't override this method then there's not really much of `ScheduleExecutorService` you can use. In principle you could implement your own subclass of `ThreadPoolExecutor` that honours the `ScheduledExectuorService` but that involves implementing a custom `BlockingQueue` which is quite a complicated thing to get right.

The simplest thing is to use a Mock implementation of `ScheduleExecturoService` - there is an (incomplete) example that does exactly this on the [Mockito Wiki](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Using-Spies-(and-Fakes)).

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a `FixedClockScheduledExecutorService` for testing which I hope is helpful to some. To use it simply schedule tasks as usual, and call `elapse()` when you want to advance time and make things happen.

(There's a few minor caveats: Ordering isn't implemented, neither is shutdown logic, and it might not work over extreme time ranges. These could all be fixed if necessary).

```
class FixedClockScheduledExecutorService extends AbstractExecutorService implements ScheduledExecutorService {
    public FixedClockScheduledExecutorService() {}

    private final Collection<Job<?>> jobs = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(); //Collection must support concurrent modification. TODO: Needs ordering
    private long offsetNanos = 0;

    //Call this to advance the clock...
    public void elapse(long time, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        offsetNanos += NANOSECONDS.convert(time, timeUnit);

        for(Job<?> job: jobs) {
            if(offsetNanos >= job.initialDelayNanos) {
                jobs.remove(job);
                job.run();
            }
        }
    }

    private <V> ScheduledFuture<V> scheduleIntenal(Callable<V> callable, long delay, long period, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        Job<V> job = new Job<V>(callable, offsetNanos + NANOSECONDS.convert( delay, timeUnit), NANOSECONDS.convert(period, timeUnit));
        jobs.add(job);
        return job;
    }


    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable runnable, long delay, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        return schedule(Executors.callable(runnable, null), delay, timeUnit);
    }

    @Override
    public <V> ScheduledFuture<V> schedule(Callable<V> callable, long delay, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        return scheduleIntenal(callable, delay, 0, timeUnit);
    }

    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable runnable, long delay, long period, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        return scheduleIntenal(Executors.callable(runnable, null), delay, Math.abs(period), timeUnit);
    }

    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable runnable, long delay, long period, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        return scheduleIntenal(Executors.callable(runnable, null), delay, -Math.abs(period), timeUnit);
    }


    class Job<V> extends FutureTask<V> implements ScheduledFuture<V> {
        final Callable<V> task;
        final long initialDelayNanos;
        final long periodNanos;

        public Job(Callable<V> runner, long initialDelayNanos, long periodNanos) {
            super(runner);
            this.task = runner;
            this.initialDelayNanos = initialDelayNanos;
            this.periodNanos = periodNanos;
        }
        @Override public long getDelay(TimeUnit timeUnit) {return timeUnit.convert(initialDelayNanos, NANOSECONDS);}
        @Override public int compareTo(Delayed delayed) {throw new RuntimeException();} //Need to implement this to fix ordering.

        @Override public void run() {
            if(periodNanos == 0) {
                super.run();
            } else {
                //If this task is periodic and it runs ok, then reschedule it.
                if(super.runAndReset()) {
                   jobs.add(reschedule(offsetNanos));
                }
            }
        }

        private Job<V> reschedule(long offset) {
            if(periodNanos < 0) return new Job<V>(task, offset, periodNanos); //fixed delay
            long newDelay = initialDelayNanos;  while(newDelay <= offset) newDelay += periodNanos; //fixed rate
            return new Job<V>(task, newDelay, periodNanos);
        }
    }

    @Override public void execute(Runnable command) { schedule(command, 0, NANOSECONDS); }
    @Override public void shutdown() {}
    @Override public List<Runnable> shutdownNow() { throw new RuntimeException(); }
    @Override public boolean isShutdown() { return false;}
    @Override public boolean isTerminated() { return false;}
    @Override public boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) { return true; }
}
```

Comment: This is really freaking awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin with mockk, mocked `ScheduledExecutorService` is the way to go.

```
class MyExecutorClass() {
    fun executeSomething() {
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule( {
                // do something here
            }, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }
}
       
@Test
fun myExecutorTest() {
    // setup
    val capturingSlotRunnable: CapturingSlot<Runnable> = slot()
    mockkStatic(Executors::class)
    val mockExecutor: ScheduledExecutorService = mockk(relaxed = true)
    every { Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() } returns mockExecutor
    every { mockExecutor.schedule(capture(capturingSlotRunnable), any(), any()) } returns null
    
    // execute
    val myExecutor = MyExecutorClass()
    myExecutor.executeSomething()
    val runnable = capturingSlotRunnable.captured
    runnable.run()

    // verify
    // TODO: verify the executable block did whatever it was supposed to
}
```